# Making a configuration file in linux

Tags: makefile, autoconf

I am making a configure.ac file for a tool i made and i need to check whether pdflatex is installed  in the users system. How do i do it ? For checking for other libraries i simply included the test programs using AC_COMPILE_IFELSE, but i dont know if pdflatex can be invoked from the program.

Also is it regular practise to install all the required packages automatically using some script or i can just specify in the readme file which packages are required and then its upto user to install those packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AC_CHECK_PROG([have_pdflatex], [pdflatex], [yes], [no])` to simply check if it exists and set `have_pdflatex` to `yes` if so. It's more likely that you'll want to use `AC_PATH_PROG([PDFLATEX], [pdflatex])` to find the actual path of the program if it exists and store it in `PDFLATEX`.

I think it's best to let the user install the prerequisites themself. You don't know how they install their software (apt? yum? pacman? emerge? source?) and it wouldn't be worth the effort to try to cover all cases. It's sufficient to just mention them in the README and to test for them with Autoconf macros.